# C++ Segmentation fault on class passed to a dlsym function pointer

Tags: c++, dll, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I'm trying to implement a shared library with the following unmangled function :

```
extern "C" IGraphLib*   load_lib(const Param* p)
{
  std::cout << p << std::endl; // 0x1cf7050
  std::cout << p->getWidth() << std::endl; // segfault
  return new NibblerOpenGL(p);
}
```

I don't understand why I have a segmentation fault when trying to get p's width, since the pointer is allocated. I call the load_lib function as follows :

```
    IGraphLib*  LibLoader::load(const std::string& file, const Param* p)
    {
      this->_dlhandle = dlopen(file.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
      if (this->_dlhandle == NULL)
      {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
      }
      IGraphLib*    (*loadFunc)(const Param*);

      loadFunc = reinterpret_cast<IGraphLib* (*)(const Param*)>(dlsym(this->_dlhandle, "load_lib"));
      if (loadFunc == NULL)
      {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
      }
      std::cout << p << std::endl; // 0x1cf7050
      std::cout << p->getWidth() << std::endl; // works
      IGraphLib*    inst = loadFunc(p);

      return inst;
   }
```

The instance of p in the load_lib function is the same so I can't see why I couldn't access his member function.

What I tried but didnt work :

```
extern "C" IGraphLib* load_lib(const void* n)
{
   std::cout << ((const Nibbler*)(n))->getWidth() << std::endl;
   return new NibblerOpenGL((const Nibbler*)(n));
}
```

Comment: When you extern "C" { } only C types are expected. Normally when I see this done, the IGraphLib* and const Param* p (which I assume is a class) would normally be cast to void*'s and then inside the function they are cast to the C++ objects where safe. I would try as an experiment returning void* and accepting const void* in load_lib and see if it passes when cast inside the function.

Comment: I edited my questions with what I tried. But I dont think the problem comes from the type interpretations, since, if I dont pass anything as parameters to my load_lib function, the instance is correctly returned as a NibblerOpenGL class, without any cast. When But when I try to launch my binary with valgrind, he warns me about "client switching stacks". before the segfault. Would the problem come from there ?

Comment: It should work.., it is possible that the library is built with a different version of header (stale for example) which defines Param?

Comment: I tried to pass two const int& instead of a class and it worked, I really think that the problem comes from the fact that I tried to pass a pointer to it, and for some reason when load_lib is called with Param*, the pointer is deleted, although it still has the same address as the original pointer.

Comment: Are you able to create a lightweight repro without the OGL stuff? I mucked around with doing this from myself and I could not get a repro so it seems to be something specific with the object itself. Is Param your class of part of the OpenGL lib? If its OGL Lib, can you get it to work with your own simple class?